# How to improve the flair NER-model results?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, flair

I am new to NER and NLP in general and I want to know if I understood the material right.
So for example I have pre-trained model "ner-english-large".
I am using a model and it turns out that the model is not recognizing the right entities.

(In this example 'Dsl' wasn't marked as ORG)

```
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger
from flair.data import Corpus
from flair.trainers import ModelTrainer

tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-english-large")
sentence = Sentence("Dsl hit 100% success in sales across all the world")
tagger.predict(sentence)
sentence.get_spans('ner')
```

```
#output
[]
```

So I want to improve my model.
I am uploading this sentence to the corpus in the appropriate format.

```
columns = {0 : 'text', 1 : 'ner'}
data_folder = "train"
corpus: Corpus = ColumnCorpus(data_folder, columns)
label_type = 'ner'
label_dict = corpus.make_label_dictionary(label_type=label_type)
```

Then I am initializing the `trainer`

```
tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-english-large")
trainer = ModelTrainer(tagger, corpus)
```

But after this I am a little bit confused about what I should do next.
Before that, I tried `train` method and it worked. Data (that was previously recognized incorrectly) was recognized as needed.

```
trainer.train('fine/taggers/continued_model',
              learning_rate=0.01,
              mini_batch_size=32,
              max_epochs=6)
```

But I don't know if this is the correct method or I need to use `fine-tune`? Could you explain which approach is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

After training you can e.g. save the model.

Methods `fine_tune` and `train` are quite similar - they use different hyperparameters for training. So, if you don't provide training parameters then `fine_tune` method should give better results in general.